# Electromagnetic field to shield from EMP?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Could an electromagnetic field be use to protect against an EMP? As I understand, an EMP is an **E**lectro **M**agnetic **P**ulse, so a sufficiently powerful field should be able to deflect one, right?

Comment: a sufficiently thick metal box would work

Comment: @Jimmy360 I know that, but I'm curious about an EM field

Comment: *"so a sufficiently powerful field should be able to deflect one, right?"*...why? EM fields obey the superposition principle - they just pass through each other.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I just kind of guessed. I now know more, which is a good thing, because if I didn't, my wave of supervillainy would have come to an abrupt end much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no. The fields pass through each other, although they may interfere with each other along the way. Electromagnetic radiation is like light; if you take a flash photo in even a strongly-lit room, your subjects will still be blinded by the flash.